# Value ignored while deserializing XML object

Tags: c#, xml

I am having trouble deserializing an XML object. The raw XML shows a nonexpiredcredits value of 5, yet the object is deserialized with a value of 0. Most significantly, no exception is hit, the deserialization process just seems to skip over the element. Any help would be appreciated.

The raw XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<theObject>
    <mobilecredits>
        <nonexpirecredits>5</nonexpirecredits>
    </mobilecredits>
</theObject>
```

The Object:

```
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("theObject")]
public class mobilecreditsWrapper
{
    [XmlElement("mobilecredits")]
    public mobilecredits credits { get; set; }
}
[Serializable()]
public class mobilecredits
{
    [XmlElement("nonexpiredcredits")]
    public int nonexpiredcredits { get; set; }
}
```

The deserialization snippet:

```
XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    //T is set to mobilecreditsWrapper in the generic function this code snippet is found in
var sr = new StringReader(res);
try
{
    obj = (T)s.Deserialize(sr);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //this is not hit
}
```

Comment: sidenote: if `res` is a `stream`, you can just pass that to the `XmlSerializer` (there is no need to box it in a `StringReader`)

Comment: It's useful for getting the raw XML.

Comment: I don't get the downvote? I had a clearly defined problem, I asked for specific help. Let's not turn Stack Overflow into a stereotypical Linux forum where asking for help is akin to admitting to leprosy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tag name are not the same. 
In your XML you have `nonexpirecredits` and in your class you have `nonexpiredcredits`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you deserializing this simple xml..You can use **LINQ2XML** instead..

```
XDocument doc=XDocument.Load(yourXML);
int no=(int)doc.Descendants().Element("nonexpirecredits");
```

Comment: IntelliSense, Strongly typed objects etc.

Comment: @JuannStrauss sure..but that xml is far too small for that purpose and an overkill..

Comment: The code is part of an API wrapper which we want to resell. having strongly-typed objects will make life easier for developers and mean less time on support. XML is a relatively rare skill, hence I'm hiding it under a layer of abstraction. This also means that I can change the datalayer to EF, NHibernate, etc. without having to rewrite more than one method.

Comment: By the way, your answer is a valid one, hence I gave you some upvote love.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo - your xml attribute specifies nonexpiredcredits, but your xml has no d - you call it nonexpirecredits.